# Is the Expected Value of the gradient of a function 0 with respect to random variable x?

Tags: calculus, statistics

$p(x;θ)$ is a function of parameter θ that provides the probability of a random variable $x$. Function $f(x;θ)$ is $\Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^d$. They are differentiable with respect to $θ$ and $x$. I see many question asked about the parameter θ. But what about

$$\Bbb E [ ∇_xf(x;θ) ]$$

I had some little thought begining like this:

$$\int∇_xp(x;θ)f(x;θ)dx$$

What's the intuition for the next step?

Comment: Use `\theta` instead.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo okay thank you for editing! I think of using integrations by parts, does it worth a try?

Comment: What is the gradient of a vector field?

Comment: I don't think it's specified, could be a member inside exponential family